# How can I delay transform of couple of elements - css3?

Tags: jquery, html, css, delay

this is my first question here and I hope I will find what I am looking for because I am out of ideas :(

So, this is what I have right now: http://capto.free.bg (sorry about the domain, I just have it uploaded here right now) .. so, it is really at the very beginning

My idea is:
When you scroll down a little, you see alternative navigation button fixed to the top. When you click it, an alternative menu is opened BUT I want these element to open one by one with some kind of delay.

Is there a way to do that? It is really important to me to do this so any help is really appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, http://www.sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transitions are made using cubic-bezier. You can set the timing to be like 1 second and move right away on the first one, and on the second one you could make it start at 1 second, and last untill 2 seconds. Repeat with bigger numbers for the next ones

Comment: Oh yeah, I have just found out how can I set the delay to my nav holder so it appears with delay after the button is clicked. Now I just need to set these to the elements. Thank you!